# Unable to run all values from csv file while doing a performance test

Tags: performance, visual-studio, performance-testing, webtest

Im using VS Web Performance Test Tool. 
My Application has a login and few functionalities but doesnt have a logout . I one closes the browser and opens , it asks for login .

Now, i have 5 rows in excel , but only the first is run and it stops. 
Please let me know if anyone knows how to make all rows run.

Thanks,
SK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, running a Web Performance Test (WPT) only does one execution of the test. A WPT can be called from a Visual Studio Load Test to run it many times by many virtual (i.e. simulated) users (VUs).

A data driven WPT can easily be run more than once by either of two methods.

1. After the test has been run once, click the "Edit run settings" on the Web Test results viewer. The modified run settings only apply to runs started by clicking the "Click here to run again" and are lost when the Web Test results viewer is closed. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243189(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.
2. The default can be changed in a `.testsettings` file. If no such file is already in the solution, then use the context (right click) menu of the solution in Solution Explorer and select `Add` => `New item` then follow the prompts to add a `Test settings` file. The `Web test` section of the file controls how WPTs are executed. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.